# Can robot framework click on plain text?

Tags: robotframework

I have a need to click on plain texts a few times to activate a module.My code is

```
FOR    ${index}     IN RANGE    6
    Log    ${index}
    Wait and Click Element                          text='SNAPSHOT'
END
```

And html block is

```
<div _ngcontent-lxw-c204=""><span _ngcontent-lxw-c204="">Versio: 5.8.4-SNAPSHOT</span><span _ngcontent-lxw-c204="" class="Test-version"></span><!----></div>
```

But always the error is cannot find the text .

Comment: Which UI library are you using? Because "text" is not a supported one in SeleniumLibrary; can't comment for the Browser one. Plus, your element's text is not "Snapshot", it obviously is "Versio: 5.8.4-SNAPSHOT".

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet, I would suggest doing it like this. Instead of using text attribute, I would use XPath expression.

```
Click Element    //*[contains(text(), "SNAPSHOT")]
```

I don't know the keyword `Wait and Click Element`. Can you please provide me with more info about this keyword?